# object has no attribute when removing stop words with NLTK

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to remove stopwords from the stopwords collection of NLTK from a pandas DataFrame that consists of rows of text data in Python 3:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

file_path = '/users/rashid/desktop/webtext.csv'
doc = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
texts = doc['text']
filter = texts != ""
dfNew = texts[filter]

stop = stopwords.words('english')
dfNew.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
```

I am getting this error:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: By default apply is applied to each column, so you probably have a column with float values. Could you add some sample data, along with the expected output?

Comment: Can you check if you have NaN values? I suspect that you are trying to split a NaN value. Try dfNew.isnull().sum()

Comment: convert float to strings by `dfNew =texts[filter].fillna(' ').astype(str)`

Comment: Can you post sample input data in question.

Comment: Once you resolve the empty value problem, change `x.split()` to `nltk.word_tokenize(x)`. If your data contains real text, this will separate punctuation correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have some numbers in your texts and they are causing pandas to get a little too smart. Add the `dtype` option to `pandas.read_csv()` to ensure that everything in the column `text` is imported as a string:

```
doc = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", dtype={'text':str})
```

Once you get your code working, you might notice it is slow: Looking things up in a list is inefficient. Put your stopwords in a set like this, and you'll be amazed at the speedup. (The `in` operator works with both sets and lists, but has a huge difference in speed.)

```
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Finally, change `x.split()` to `nltk.word_tokenize(x)`. If your data contains real text, this will separate punctuation from words and allow you to match stopwords properly.